# Como traduzir a frase em Inglês "you made me feel welcome" num jeito que pareça natural?

Tags: português-brasileiro, vocabulário, expressões-equivalentes, frases

Eu não sei como expressar esse sentimento em português, mas o povo do Brasil me deu muita razão para falar isso. A frase melhor que eu consigo pensar é "me fez sentir em casa" mas não é a mesma coisa.

Atualização: o aspeto mais importante é que quando alguém "feels welcome" por causa de umas pessoas, há o impressão que essas pessoas realmente estão felizes por passar tempo com ele. Essa distinção importa porque é possível receber alguém bem por vários motivos, seja por isso ser o seu dever, seja por você ser uma pessoa boa e receber alguém bem porque é educado fazer isso. Então, dizer que você "felt welcome" é mais do que só dizer que se sentiu bem recebido,  ou que todo mundo estava muito amigável consigo; é um jeito de dizer que quando você passou tempo com essas pessoas, sim todo mundo estava muito querido, mas também que você não sentiu que estivesse incomodando ninguém.

Espero que essa explicação seja compreensível, é difícil explicar um conceito assim numa segunda lingua.

Muito obrigado todo mundo.

Answer (score 10):

This answer is about **pt-BR**

The literal translation is, of course, **"vocês fizeram com que eu me sentisse bem-vindo."**  It doesn't sound idiomatic in pt-BR, though.  One more natural way of saying it would be your own suggestion, to which I add a few more.

> - "vocês fizeram com que eu me sentisse em casa"
> - "vocês me receberam muito bem." or "senti-me muito bem recebido."
> - "fiquei surpreso com a forma hospitaleira como fui recebido"
> - "fiquei feliz pela forma calorosa como fui recebido por vocês."
> - "fiquei muito feliz com a forma amigável com que todos me trataram."

You can call them "literary translations" because, although the word "welcome" is not mentioned, they all mean that you felt welcome.  If you've been to Rio and felt that your hosts were very friendly, warm and helpful, these literary translations would fit better.

Comment: Let me point out that `(...) me sentisse em casa` has an extra nuance after the other sentences -> (for the other sentences,) you can be very well-received e.g. in a diplomatic context, and feel very well-taken-care-of... without feeling "at home".

Comment: @ANeves   This may be opinion-based but when I was a student in the U.S. everybody was so friendly to me that I felt at home.  And I can say that "eles fizeram com que eu me sentisse em casa".  Of course that's a figure of speech because there´s no place like home for one to feel at home.  What is really meant is that they made me feel very comfortable, as if I were in my own country.

Comment: I agree with that. I just meant that "me sentisse em casa" has more meaning than the others; maybe like "ter saudade de" means more than "lembrar-se de" and maybe even "sentir falta de".

Comment: Hi, I'm looking back on this answer, and though they are good suggestions, what I still feel they are missing from "feeling welcome" is the feeling that people are happy to have you with them. While being well-received or feeling at home do get a point across, the essence of "welcomeness" is not so much exactly how you were treated, but the impression that your presence is wanted i.e. not that anyone is doing you a favour; there is a genuine motive behind any gestures of goodwill.  It's a very specific concept, I know, so perhaps there isn't such an idiomatic translation of it. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Some_Guy  "Eu me senti muito bem recebido e até mesmo querido por todos".

Answer (score 6):

The literal translation *fazer alguém sentir-se bem-vindo* is possible. *Bem-vindo* is not just an interjection, it can be used an adjective. See for instance the definition in [Aulete](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/bem-vindo):

> 1. Recebido com prazer; acolhido com satisfação [Received with pleasure; hosted with satisfaction]: *Você é sempre **bem-vindo** em nossa casa.*

This mirrors the definition of *welcome* from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/welcome):

> 1. (of a guest or new arrival) gladly received.
>      *‘I'm pleased to see you, lad—you're welcome’*

The pattern of the example above (*ser bem-vindo*) is more common than *sentir-se bem-vindo*, but you can find the latter here and there. Here is one of the four instances in CETEMPúblico that I could find:

> *par=ext411125-soc-93a-2*: Autenticamente «british», talvez, para grande desgosto dos portugueses, que nunca **se sentiram bem-vindo[s]** no Algarve .

*Fazer alguém sentir-se em casa* is indeed more idiomatic, but it conveys an idea of belonging.

Besides the literal translation, all I can think is:

> Fui muito bem recebido. / Receberam-me muito bem.

which, however, puts the focus on how you were treated, rather than how you feel.

Comment: I thought of a variation of your last example, *fizeram-me sentir (muito) bem recebido*, which mirrors the OP example. I thought it sounds more  natural than *fizeram-me sentir bem-vindo*, but on Google  the *bem recebido* version is even rarer than the *bem-vindo* one.

Comment: 'Sentir acolhido' ou 'sentir à vontade' can be an option?